# A history of logarithms and exponential functions

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, math-history

I know that :

$$\ln: (0,+\infty )\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$\ln(x):=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}$$

---

And :

$$\ln^{-1}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$$
$$\ln^{-1}(x):=\exp(x)$$

---

after that. We define :

$$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$$
$$f(x):=\big(\exp(\ln a)\big)^x \ \ \ a >0 ,a \neq 1$$

---

And :

$$f^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f^{-1}(x):=\log_a (x) \ \ \ a >0 ,a \neq 1$$

---

now my question : function $\dfrac{1}{t}$ How did they get?

Comment: Why is "history" in your title?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro.For this purpose: How was the logarithm discovered?

Comment: See [this 1913 paper](https://archive.org/details/jstor-2974104) by Florian Cajori. Note that this is the last part of a mult-part paper. Look at the end of this paper to see the previous parts of this multi-part paper.

Comment: Another useful reference is Glasher's 1920 paper *On early tables of logarithms and the early history of logarithms*, but you might have to visit a university library (or have online access to one), since I wasn't able to find it freely available on the internet.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro. ok thank you .

Comment: For a more popular account, you might look at ["e: The Story of a Number"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=rCGM6TKHyboC)

Comment: I don't know the true history, but it seems very natural to first define $b^x$ and then define $\log_b(y)$ to be the solution to $b^x = y$. The number $e$ is discovered as the special value of $b$ that makes the derivative of $b^x$ equal to $b^x$. It seems to me that defining $\ln(x)$ to be $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \, dt$ is something someone would only think of as an afterthought, when they are searching for the most efficient way to define these functions and prove their properties rigorously (for example if they are writing a real analysis textbook).

Answer (score 2):

The discovery of (decimal) logarithms by Napier (tables published in 1614) predates by a century or so the discovery of the fact that the area between $1$ and $a$ under the hyperbola with equation $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ has a value which is proportional to a multiple of the (decimal) logarithm of $a$. It was not until the second half of the 18th century, with the fixation of notations by Euler, who in particular introduced the natural logarithm (also called Euler logarithm, now denoted $\ln$) that it became current to write

$$\int_a^b \dfrac{dx}{x}=\ln(b)-\ln(a)$$

(the integral notation was introduced only 50 years earlier, by Leibnitz).

It was the same Euler who fixed the notation $e^x$ for the exponential function, and explained in a plain way that exponential and logarithm are inverse functions one of the other.

Answer (score 2):

The May 2022 issue of *The College Mathematics Journal* will contain the article "The Equivalence of Definitions of the Natural Logarithm Function," which has some historical comments and a 25-item bibliography.

Comment: Interesting. Are you the author ? Some other references can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3119836/305862)

Comment: Yes, I am. Thanks for the references.